# Is it possible to add something to a list without trigging the ItemAdded event

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, event-handlers

I have a situation where I don't want to trigger the ItemAdded event if an item is added to a list via a workflow. Is it possible not to trigger this event?

Comment: why dont leave it empty, if you dont want it to do anything ?

Comment: When items are not added by my workflow I want to do some checks on the item.

Answer (score 5):

Might want to take a look at this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.disableeventfiring(v=office.12).aspx

Basically, what your looking for is something like this

```
base.DisableEventFiring();
item.update();
base.EnableEventFiring();
```

Answer (score 3):

Following Caesar answer I knew what to google for.

The nicest thing I have seen is from [Adrian Henke's blog](http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/)

```
/// <summary>
/// Disabled item events scope
/// </summary>
/// <see cref="http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/"/>
class DisabledItemEventsScope : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable
{
    bool oldValue;

    public DisabledItemEventsScope()
    {
        this.oldValue = base.EventFiringEnabled;
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        base.EventFiringEnabled = oldValue;
    }    

}
```

You can then call your code in:

```
using (DisabledItemEventsScope scope = new DisabledItemEventsScope())
{
    item.SystemUpdate(); // will NOT fire events
}
item.SystemUpdate(); // will fire events again
```

The nice thing is that if anything goes wrong events will be turned back on automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Could always have the workflow update a hidden column and the event receiver looks to see if there is any data in that column. If yes, do nothing, if no, process.